# Windows 7 search stopped finding programs

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

My search function under the start menu has stopped finding programs and exes which although not disasterous is a bit annoying.

Doing the following

right click task bar -> properties -> start menu tab -> customise

and looking at the search settings seems to indicate that it should include programs i.e.

[image: search settings]

but it doesn't.

Any ideas how to remedy this? I'm using windows 7.

Many Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry i need to correct this. Looks like it can't find files either. It just brings up a few top level folders i.e.

[image: broken search]

Excuse the whitespace - that how it looks onscreen. Thanks

**EDIT 2**

I've tried running the troubleshooter through the control panel. No fault found. Also I have rebuilt the indexes via control panel -> index options. Still doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something Microsoft supposedly fixed last year or so. Check whether you have the [KB977380 Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977380/en-us) installed or not. If not, you may want to give it a shot.

You can also try Microsoft's Fix it solution titled [Fix Windows Desktop Search when it crashes or not showing results](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_search/en-us) and see if you're getting some results.

If that doesn't work, you can always try to delete the following file. Looks like it can become corrupted easily.

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\1033\StructuredQuerySchema.bin
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try out as soon as I can. TBH I think my machine might have developed bigger problems. Maybe it's on it's way out. Oh well.